# How can use different css styles in different images created with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

The following `javascript` and `css` code prints two images on the screen with different positions and it works perfectly fine.

```js
print_first_image();
print_second_image();

function print_first_image() {
   const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
   img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1';
   img.style.top = '150px';
   img.style.left = '50px';
}

function print_second_image() {
   const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
   img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1';
   img.style.top = '50px';
   img.style.left = '50px';
}
```

```css
img {
   position:absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

However, I'd like to **set the position of those images in two separated css functions** instead of defining their position on the `javascript` code as I'm currently doing. The **pseudocode** of what I want to do is something like this:

Javascript:

```
print_first_image();
print_second_image();
function print_first_image() {
   const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
   img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1';
}

function print_second_image() {
   const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img2'));
   img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1';
}
```

css:

```
img {
   position:absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   top: 150px;
   left: 50px;
}

img2 {
   position:absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   top: 50px;
   left: 50px;
}
```

The only difference is that I want to declare the `top` and `left` attributes with `css` instead of doing it with javascript. How can I do it?

Comment: You can simply add a class to each one when you create them. The CSS could define different positions for each class.

Comment: @TylerRoper But how exactly can I do it? I have found examples of creating classes and using them with `html` like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_class) from  w3school. But I'm having trouble to find how I can create css classes and access them from javascript code...

Comment: `img.classList.add("class-name-here");` - [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tyler Roper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434398/how-can-use-different-css-styles-in-different-images-created-with-javascript#comment89839844_51434398) stated in the comments simply adding a class to each image when I create them solves the problem... So here is the complete functional code that worked for me:

```js
print_first_image();
print_second_image();

function print_first_image() {
   const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
   img.classList.add("image1");
   img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1';
}

function print_second_image() {
   const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
   img.classList.add("image2");
   img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1';
}
```

```css
.image1 {
   position:absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   top: 50px;
   left: 50px;
}

.image2 {
   position:absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   top: 150px;
   left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the css must be:

```
img {
 position:absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 top :150px;
 left :50px;
}

img2 {
 position:absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 left:50px;
}
```

it's ':' not '='

Comment: Ah yeah, that was a typo that I made when I was asking the question... But actually just changing `=` by `:` doesn't make the code functional...

Comment: @Ramuyko It is a good choice to add a different class to each tag.